# Outlook 2003, compose window shuts down after a while, using Word

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, microsoft-office-2003, microsoft-word-2003

I've got a user that uses MS Office 2003, with Word as the email editor in Outlook.

I had a nice session of Windows Update and Security Essentials to clean up a few virus and bring the box up to date (Windows Update was borked and the box had received no updates in ages).

After doing that, we have found out that when composing an email, the compose window closes automatically after a few seconds.

Googling around I've found hints to recreate normal.dot to solve the issue, and will try that later... but anyone has other suggestions?

Regards,

Alex

Comment: and recreating normal.dot does not help...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've found the problem. It seems to be "smart" tags. Disabling smart tags seems to solve the problem.